# Удаление дубликатов из первого вектора посредством значений из второго вектора(без сортировки)

Tags: c++, vector

Всем добрый вечер.
Нарисовалась такая проблема.
Никак не могу удалить дубликаты значений в первом векторе.
Сравниваюсь со значениями, которые находятся во втором векторе.
Бегу и проверяю по одному значению весь вектор.
Написал вот такую функцию. Предполагаю, что проблема с выходом за границы, но никак не могу победить...
Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

```
//    v{1,3,5,6,7,6,4,8}
//    v2{1,2,3,5,7,8}
        void dropDupl(std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<int>& v2)
        {
            int cht = 0;
            for (auto base = v.begin(); base != v.end(); )
            {
            
                for (auto base2 = v2.begin(); base2 != v2.end(); ++base)
                {
                    cht++;
                    if (*base == *base2)
                    {
                        v.erase(base);
                    }
                }
            }
        
        }
```

Comment: Напомню на всякий случай, что `erase()` [*Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).

Comment: цикл у вас непонятный убегает только `++base` , а `base2` стоит на месте. Плавным решением проблем будет использовать индексы вместо итераторов. И не забывать когда и что прибавлять, а когда нет. И не забыть увеличивать индекс у `v2`.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, учту

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый цикл не меняет итератор. Второй цикл меняет чужой итератор. Если это исправить, ваш код перестанет рушиться (наверно), но проблема останется.

Не надо менять вектор по которому вы итерируетесь. Эта проблема такая распространнённая что для её решения придумана идиома [erase-remove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). Годные элементы сдвигаются в начало вектора (`remove`), когда весь вектор обработан его хвост обрезается (`erase`).

Если менять ваш код как можно меньше получится что-то такое:

```
void dropDupl(std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<int>& v2)
{
    auto dupl = [&v2](auto value)
    {
        for (auto base2 = v2.begin(); base2 != v2.end(); ++base2)
        {
            if (value == *base2)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), dupl), v.end());
}
```

Или такое:

```
void dropDupl(std::vector<int>& v, const std::vector<int>& v2)
{
    auto dupl = [&v2](auto value)
    {
        return std::find(v2.begin(), v2.end(), value) != v2.end();
    };

    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), dupl), v.end());
}
```

**P.S.** Рекомендую тип `v2` поменять на `set` или `unordered_set`. Будет намного быстрее.

**P.P.S.** Если вам интересно как устроен `remove_if`...

`p` пробегает все элементы `v`. `q` указывает на элемент за последним годным. В начале пока все элементы ещё годные, `p` и `q` двигаются синхронно. Как только пройден первый негодный элемент, `q` начнёт отставать от `p`, а присваивание начнёт сдвигать годные элементы левее. После цикла все годные элементы собраны в начале вектора, `q` указывает на позицию за последним годным элементом:

```
template<typename Vector, typename Pred>
typename Vector::iterator remove_if(Vector& v, Pred pred)
{
    auto q = v.begin();
    for (auto p = v.begin(); p != v.end(); ++p) {
        if (!pred(*p)) {
            *q = *p;
            ++q;
        }
    }
    return q;
}
```

[Настоящий исходный код `remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove#Version_3) имеет другой интерфейс, и работает быстрее за счёт исключения самоприсваиваний.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли @StanislavVolodarskiy

Answer (score 0):

Команда `erase` портит итераторы и дальнейший цикл с ними не возможен. Цикл по указателям тоже не пойдёт, так как расположение в памяти может измениться.
Постоянная работа с памятью портит производительность, так-что желательно пока память не трогать.
*Ваши циклы неправильны, так как вы забываете добавлять `++ base2`*
Пробуем цикл делать по индексам и при нахождении дубля делаем `swap` с последним элементом. После всей работы в конце избавляемся от этих дублей, что остались в конце вектора.

```cpp
# include <vector>
void dropDupl ( std::vector<int>& v , std::vector<int> const & v2 ) {
  std::size_t vs = v . size ( ) ;
  for ( std :: size_t i = 0; i < vs ; ++ i ) {
    for ( auto base2 = v2.cbegin(); base2 != v2.cend(); ++base2 ) {
      if ( v [ i ] == * base2 ) {
        // дубли проверять не будем
        -- vs ;
        // заменяем последний элемент с этим местом
        std :: swap (v[i],v[vs]);
        // продолжим проверять с этого-же места
        -- i ;
        // выходим из второго цикла поиска
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  // теперь уже остальные элементы забываем
  v . resize ( vs ) ;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код меняет порядок. А это не порядок.

Comment: не нашёл условия, что ускорять нельзя. вот и воспользовался.. @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Есть решение за линейное время, которое сохраняет порядок.

Comment: то есть не **swap** , а как в **remove** `if(..){..[i] = ..[j] ; ++ i ;} ++ j ;` .  тоже неплохо. @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Всё равно, огромное спасибо за помощь @AlexGlebe